# TypeScript Augmenting Window not working in separate files

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, window

I'm looking to add another property to `window`. I can do that with this:

```
// global.d.ts

import { IConfig } from './src/models';
export {};

declare global {
    interface Window {
        _env: IConfig;
    }
}
```

But then when I try to reference this new property in a different file, it complains:

```
// src/util.ts

// Property '_env' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
export const URL = `https://example.com/${window._env.path}`;
```

But when I combine these into the same file, everything is fine and there are no errors. Is there anyway I can have these in a separate file?

I'm using TypeScript 4.1.2.

Comment: Hope this will be helpful: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/declaring-global-variables-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

I went down a bit of a rabbit hole but found this relevant [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)

I was able to accomplish this exactly as you have written (different type of course) in an existing angular 8 project and svelte project using their existing polyfills.ts files for my global declaration.

Are you sure you tsconfig.json is compiling everything correctly?